# Lighning Experience Cache issue with Static Resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I have the next Code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute  name="logo"                 type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute  name="staticResourceString" type="String"/>
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12  slds-align_absolute-center" style="max-width:15rem; ">
    <c:OLImage wd="8rem;" res="{!v.staticResourceString}" /> 
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center"  style="width:8rem"> 
        <img src="{!v.staticResourceString}"/>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller
({

```
onInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.resolveLogoStaticResource(component);
    },
})
```

Helper

```
({
resolveLogoStaticResource : function (component){
        let logoName = component.get("v.logo");

        let logoResourceName = "{!$Resource." + logoName + "}";
        component.set("v.staticResourceString", logoResourceName);
    },
})
```

OLImage.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="wd"     type="String"  />
    <aura:attribute name="owd"    type="String"  />
    <aura:attribute name="res"    type="String"  />
    <aura:attribute name="class"  type="String"  default="slds-align_absolute-center"/>
    <div class="{!v.class}"  style="{!'width:' + v.wd}"> 
            <img src="{!v.res}"/> 
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

As you see , the OLImage.cmp  has only an `<img>` tag that is reproduced on the parent cmp.

But the results are diferents:

[image]

OLImage.cmp resolves the received String and retrieves the Static resource.
the img tag, does not resolve the attribute.

[image]

It's a really strange issue. Does anyone knows why it happens?

Comment: how are you getting `staticResourceString` value?

Comment: @salesforce-sas i'm building it in the onInit method

Comment: can u show that also? I am unable to reproduce this

Comment: @salesforce-sas i added more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have implemented in javascript is not correct way of getting static resource url. You can refer to [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm) to understand the difference. In javascript you should use `$A` API.

You should use below method in HELPER js:

```
resolveLogoStaticResource  : function(component) {
    component.set("v.staticResourceString",$A.get('$Resource.'+component.get("v.logo")));
},
```

Comment: You are right, it solved the issue.

My confussion started because OLImage.cmp resolves the resource directly from the attribute.